# Extract tarball with Apache Camel?

Tags: compression, gzip, integration, apache-camel, tar

Is there a built-in / contributed component to *gunzip* a tarball? There is a [gzip data format](http://camel.apache.org/gzip-data-format.html), but it does not seem to handle files.

Comment: Hey @miku - did you get a solution to this?

Comment: @DaveH, not really, unfortunately - but I haven't looked at it for a long time.

Comment: There is recently added in camel 2.16.0 tarfile dataformat https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9111

Answer (score 0):

camel file marshalling/unmarshalling using gzip should be supported, see this unit test for a basic example

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/impl/GzipDataFormatFileUnmarshalDeleteTest.java

Comment: This is nice for *gzipped* files. The problem is that `tar` will bundle a bunch of files before compression.